# Перемещение объекта с помощью ScrollBar Unity

Tags: unity3d

Вечер добрый! Решил сделать концепцию перемещения объекта пользователем скроллбаром, однако нигде не могу найти информацию насчет получения ввода со скроллбара для перемещения, в любом случае выдает ошибку "Невызываемый член "Scrollbar.Direction" не может использоваться как метод".

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `Scrollbar.Value` который возвращает значение от 0.0 до 1.0 в зависимости от положения ползунка.

Для определения направления можно указать середину ползунка значением 0.5, и сохранять в отдельном поле.

```
Vector3 direction = scrollbar.Value >= 0.5 ? Vector3.right : Vector3.left;
```

Для движения можно использовать любой удобный для вас способ на примере покажу на `Vector3.MoveTowards()

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, direction, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime)
```

Comment: Благодарю! Вчера тыкался и переделал, вместо скроллбара поставил слайдер, так как хоть какой-то адекватный учебник в инете нашел по нему. Поставлю скроллбар потом, так как его проще кастомить потом. Всего 2 недели этим занимаюсь, чувствую себя первоклассником xD Мерси))

Comment: @iamsoltanov, это нормально, для этого и существуют такие площадки, чтобы помогать друг другу, лучшая благодарность это отметить ответ как верный, галочкой)

Comment: сделал, тут тоже пытаюсь разобраться)